# Update item from Dataset adaptor

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to update a row brought back from a dataset adaptor. I'm clearly doing something wrong but my googling/logic keeps failing me.

Heres what I have;

```
Public Class Popup
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private dtJobs As Barry.joblistDataTable
    Private taJobs As New BarryTableAdapters.joblistTableAdapter
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim Type As String = Request.QueryString("t")

        Select Case Type
            Case "cancel"
                CancelLocation(Request.QueryString("t"))

        End Select

    End Sub

    Protected Sub CancelLocation(ByVal JobNo As String)

        dtJobs = New Barry.joblistDataTable
        dtJobs = taJobs.GetByJobNo(JobNo)

        dtJobs.Item("Status") = "Cancelled"

        taJobs.Update(dtJobs)


    End Sub
End Class
```

The database field is called Status and I want to put the string of Cancelled in there

Comment: Does your BarryTableAdapters.joblistTableAdapter contain valid UpdateCommand?

Comment: What is `dtJobs`? A (strongly typed) `DataTable` has no `Item` property. So this would not compile: `dtJobs.Item("Status")`

Comment: `Case "cancel" : CancelLocation(Request.QueryString("t"))`. Now `Request.QueryString("t")` is either `cancel` or `JobNo`, not both. it seems you passed wrong input to `CancelLocation`